# I want to add 15 minutes slot to each StartTime in a loop and store in array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

```
 const createTimeSlots=(fromTime,toTime)=>{
```

I want to add 15 minutes slot to each StartTime in a loop and store in array of objects.

Comment: take the difference of endTime and startTime, divide it by 15 minute; you will get the possible number of slots, then iterate through slot using for loop and add 15 minute in startTime and push it to result array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inputs are in timestamp, add 15 mins equivalent of timestamps and push that timestamp(or push mins/hrs etc.). Here's the code example where start time is current timestamp and endtime is current + 3hrs in timestamp.

```js
   function createSlots(start, end) {
    let slots = [];
    const mins = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 mins

    const date = (dt) => new Date(dt);

    while (start <= end) {
        start += mins;

        // only mins
        //slots.push(date(start).getMinutes());

        // hrs +  mins
        slots.push(`${date(start).getHours()}:${date(start).getMinutes()}`);
    }
    return slots;
}

var slots = createSlots(Date.now(), Date.now() + 3 * 3600 * 1000); // from (now) to (now + 3hrs)
console.log("slots : ", slots);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume inputs are valid date-time format.
This solution will work across dates, let's say you give the start time today and end time tomorrow then also it will work without any issue.

```js
const createTimeSlots = (fromTime, toTime, slotLength =15*60) => {
    let slotStart = new Date(fromTime).valueOf();
    let slotEnd = new Date(fromTime).valueOf() + slotLength * 1000;
    let endEpoch = new Date(toTime).valueOf();
    let ob = [];
    for (slotEnd; slotEnd <= endEpoch; slotEnd = slotEnd + slotLength * 1000) {
        ob.push({
            'from': formatDate(slotStart),
            'to': formatDate(slotEnd)
        });
        slotStart = slotEnd;
    }
    return ob;
}

function formatDate(epoch) {
    let d = new Date(epoch);
    let month = String((d.getMonth() + 1)).padStart(2, '0');
    let day = String((d.getDate())).padStart(2, '0');
    let hours = String((d.getHours())).padStart(2, '0');
    let mins = String((d.getMinutes())).padStart(2, '0');

    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${mins}`;
}

const from = "2022-05-25 23:00";
const to = "2022-05-26 01:00";
const slotLength = 15 * 60; //seconds
var r = createTimeSlots(from, to, slotLength );
console.log(r);
```